# excel/google sheets: How to sum values seperated by Colon(:)

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Can you help me?

How to sum values separated by colon

```
A1    A2         A3
3:0   5:9        4:5
```

To get sum like - `12:14`

Comment: If its a one time thing, you can transpose your data, use text to column to separate the values on the `:` into two columns. then sum each column and concatenate the result.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably more clever ways to do it than this, but the most obvious way that comes to mind is to split the string into two components:  one to the left of the colon and one to the right of the colon.  You could do this in separate cells just to the side of the data you are working on.

For example, assume you have in cells A1, A2, and A3, the values "7:555", "88:77", and "34:987" respectively.

- In columns B1, you could put the function **=NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A1, FIND(":", A1) - 1))** to split out the left part of the string and convert it to a number.
- Then copy this formula down column B to match the number of rows in column A
- In Columns c1, c2, and C3, you could put the function **=NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - FIND(":", A1)))**
- Then copy this formula down column C to match the number of rows in column A
- Finally, just do a sum on column B to sum the left hand side and sum on column C to get the right hand side

Bonus, if you didn't want to show your work, you could hide columns B and C.

Super bonus, and probably over-thinking it, you could be a VBA macro.

Comment: =NUMBERVALUE(...) did not work on Google Sheets. I recommend you change the formula to =VALUE(...) if you are using Google Sheets instead of Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMPRODUCT and parse the string:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--LEFT(A1:A3,FIND(":",A1:A3)-1))&":"&SUMPRODUCT(--MID(A1:A3,FIND(":",A1:A3)+1,LEN(A1:A3)))
```

[image]